# ubuntu apt-get update slow at begining

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

recently I feel apt-get update runs much slower for some servers than others.

```
xxx@xxx:/usr/lib/php5/20121212$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist InRelease
```

some servers execute `apt-get update` and less than half a second the second line above show up. while other servers take about 5 seconds to show up the second line.

I `sudo strace apt-get update` and find that slow servers will stop at bellow for several second

```
open("/etc/apt/sources.list", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "# \n\n# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 1"..., 8191) = 3488
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f0ab30f3a50) = 30800
close(6)                                = 0
fcntl(5, F_GETFL)                       = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0ab2f68000
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
read(5, "i386\n    <----------------- here
```

after several second it continue as bellow

```
                , 4096)                 = 5
read(5, "", 4096)                       = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=30800, si_status=0, si_utime=307, si_stime=167} ---
close(5)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f0ab2f68000, 4096)
```

outputs are almost the same for all servers.

how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it is the server or the network connection speed between the box and the source on the net? A bogged down network or machine would alter that. ...or the specs on one box being more powerful than another (better processor, more ram...)

Comment: Without knowing the specs on the networks and the boxes, and the load on either of those, there is not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: Basically unless you are comparing two servers which are hardware and sofware identical and on the same portion of the same net, then you are most likely comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 3):

finally，my friend find out the problem.

It caused by open files limit which we set it very large for our system user. It's a bug of ubuntu.

we set a much smaller open files limit an apt-get update become fast.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1332440